# Median vs mean in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, mean, median, cloudmasking

I applied the cloud masking on Sentinel 2 imagery in GEE. The original image collection without masking clouds is this:

[image]

First I tried the script exactly as written at the bottom of this page [Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-2A](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR)
and I got this result:

[image]

I saw other tutorials that other people use `median`,  so the second time I deleted 'mean' in the last line here:

```
Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');
```

Instead I added 'median' in the image collection variable:

```
 .map(maskS2clouds)
 .median();
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I realized `median ()` produces much clearer image, however I am not sure about differences between `median ()` and `mean`and since `mean` was used in the GEE website, I do not know if I am doing right by using median and having such a clear image!

Comment: If your objective is to have a less cloudy image, the median is fine, it is commonly used. Think about it as a series of values, where every value is a pixel on a different date. If you apply the min, max, mean, median, etc. What you are doing is selecting the pixel that matches that statistic on the time series.